# Make rate button launch marketplace and have message body show

Tags: java, android

i would like to have my rate button in my dialog to launch marketplace and go to my specific app.

Also how do i add in a message body into this dialog?

```
        private void makeDialog() {     

        AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);      

        about.setMessage("About The Giveaway");

        about.setPositiveButton("Rate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//action
            }
        });

        about.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
        });

        about.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the Market app using an Intent. Add this to your positiveButton onClick (replacing the URL with your app url)

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
    "android.intent.action.VIEW", 
    Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.animoca.prettyPetSalon");
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple library to do that.

It is called **[AppRate](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate)** and you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate).

### Features:

- Do not prompt the user if the app has crashed once.
- Decide exaclty when to prompt the user. (number of launches ...)
- Customize the rate dialog to fit your application design.

### Usage example:

It is very easy to install and use:

Drop the [jar](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate/downloads) in your `libs` folder.

Then include the following code in the `onCreate` method of your `MAIN` activity.

```
new AppRate(this)
    .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
    .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(0)
    .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(20)
    .init();
```

- This code will show a default rate dialog after 20 lauches.
- It will be shown only if the app has never crashed.
- The rate button points to your application in the Google Play Store.

I hope this can help you. :)